# An image/icon opens the date selector

Tags: php, datepicker

I have an `HTML`/ `PHP` website which has an **image-icon** (looks like a calendar) that I want users to click and open the default datepicker.

The user selects the date which gets saved in **`mySQL`** and *echoed* somewhere else, say under the calendar image.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Did you tryed something ?

Comment: <input name="mycal" type="date" class="a1" id="mycal" value="" size="10" />

But this just gives me a textfield with options to select dates etc. I want an img that opens the date selector

Comment: And when the date is selected, I want it to be echoed at a different location

Comment: @sohelmugal : please look at the answer and ask if you want any further clarifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML :

```
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" style="display:none">
```

jQuery :

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date"
    });
  });
  </script>
```

You will need the following resources too :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Working [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/apuz8qyn/1/)

---

Once you have the date selected in the text-box , you can have its value by simply the `$_POST["inputName"]` in your PHP script.

Comment: Thanks a mil, but my problem is I do not want to show the text field next to the calendar.gif. I want calendar.gif to be the only thing that user sees. I want the selected date to show as text somewhere else.

Comment: put this in the style tag of your input tag : `style:"display:none"`

Comment: @sohelmugal : Do you understand the code  ? do you have any questions ?

Comment: Can I use this for time also

Comment: absolutely! My suggestion would be instead of directly displaying the date on some other page , show the date first on the current page and then redirect to other page.

Comment: Accepted: Yes I understand, the "display:none" is the catch I guess.

Comment: Yes ! :) The user will be more comfortable if shown what he has selected from the datepicker

Comment: @sohelmugal : I hope you were satisfied with the answer ? Happy coding :)